# SEND MULTIPLE MESSAGES IN DIALOGFLOW

Tags: dialogflow-es

How to send Consequtive(multiple messages) in dialogflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It chooses a suitable response randomly, to make it sound more conversational.

Most platforms can only send one or two messages as part of the reply. If you have more than one thing to say at once - combine them.

If your response gets too long - your system may not be as conversational as you think it is.